# Import Subversion repository into Git

Tags: git, svn, import

I have an existing SVN repository at http://svn.donnael.com/lilypond/SousaFairest. Out of curiosity, I created a repository at https://github.com/SarekOfVulcan/donnael-Scores as well, and added some files to it. Can I now take the Sousa folder and import that into the GitHub directory, maintaining the change history, or is that more trouble than it's worth? (I have a decent understanding of svn, but git is brand new to me.)

Comment: I did read the information about importing at create time, but that wasn't what I wanted to do. I suppose I could blow the whole thing away and start from scratch, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do it starting from where I am now. Thanks.

Comment: There is a help page on GitHub about importing SVN repos, if you haven't read it yet: http://help.github.com/import-from-subversion/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that would be possible. There may be a way to do it all from one local repo, but I'm pretty confident that this would work. Assuming you're starting from scratch with no local repos:

- `git svn clone` your SVN repo to a local git repo (hereafter known as svn-repo)
- `git clone` your github repo to a local repo (known as github-repo)
- In github-repo, `git remote add svn-repo <url>` using a [local file URL](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html#URLS)
- `git fetch svn-repo`
- `git merge svn-repo/master` to merge the master branch of svn-repo into github-repo
- Then just push to github

Comment: I couldn't quite get this to work, but I assume it's just a misconfiguration problem. I'll bang on it some more later.

Answer (score 2):

There are many tutorials online about importing subversion into git.  As far as it being a hassle, it's only (3-4 commands).  It's worth doing, unless you don't want to keep your svn repo's history.

Here's [githubs](http://help.github.com/import-from-subversion/) guide to pulling it off